# Error during AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-view

I have a fragment which contains a list. The list is placed in `SwipeRefreshLayout`
I found a bug that occurs in this situation:

if during the operation SwipeRefreshLayout's `onRefresh()` I'll pass on druoy fragment, the application crashes.

in may onRefresh:

```
@Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        if (InternetResiver.isOnline(getActivity())) {
          setData();
        } else {
            AlertDialog alert = InternetResiver.getAlertDialog(getActivity());
            alert.show();
        }
}
```

in setData() :

```
public void setData(){

        new MyAsincTask(getActivity()){
            int city = 0;
            int holiday = 0;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Document document) {
                super.onPostExecute(document);
                ArrayList<EmployeesListBean> employeesListBeans = new ArrayList<>();
                Elements elementsUid = document.select("uid");
                Elements elementsStaffName = document.select("staff_name");
                ....

                for (int i = 0; i < elementsUid.size(); i++) {
                    EmployeesListBean employeesListBean = new EmployeesListBean();
                    employeesListBean.setUid(elementsUid.get(i).ownText());
                    employeesListBean.setStaff_name(elementsStaffName.get(i).ownText());
                   ....

                    employeesListBeans.add(employeesListBean);

                    if (employeesListBeans.get(i).getOut_time().equals("на смене") && elementsLocation.get(i).ownText().equals("city")) {
                        city += 1;
                    }
                    if(employeesListBeans.get(i).getOut_time().equals("на смене") && elementsLocation.get(i).ownText().equals("holiday")){
                        holiday += 1;
                    }
                }
                EmployeeListAdapter sectionedAdapter = new EmployeeListAdapter(employeesListBeans, getActivity());
                listView.setAdapter(sectionedAdapter);
                progressDialog.cancel();
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                getActivity().setTitle("Сотрудники(city:" + city + ",holiday:" + holiday + ")");
            }
        }.execute(link);
    }
```

error:

```
12-23 11:49:14.708    1332-1332/com.managment.pavel.managmentgradle E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.managment.pavel.managmentgradle.fragments.EmployeessList$1.onPostExecute(EmployeessList.java:113)
            at com.managment.pavel.managmentgradle.fragments.EmployeessList$1.onPostExecute(EmployeessList.java:69)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

line with error:

```
getActivity().setTitle("Сотрудники(city:" + city + ",holiday:" + holiday + ")");
```

what to do when pravelno Navigate to the new fragment during operation AsyncTask? and how to solve my problem?

Comment: yould it be that getActivity() returns null?

Comment: out when I turn on the new fragment is trying to execute a method getActivity().setTitle but I have a new fragment

Comment: could it be that the fragment is not visible/attached anymore?

Comment: you could check for getActivity() == null and then not set the title or wait till the asynctask is completed and then change the fragment

Comment: When you use fragment you must pay attention to the lifecycle. Try to debug or log if you pass first for you line with error on in the onActivityCreated callback.

Comment: I'm telling you. when I run the stream and quickly move on to the next fragment, it happens. ie a fragment which was launched stream is already closed

Comment: can you try 'activity_name.getActivity()'

Comment: but the thread is still running. and when he quits, I on the other fragment. And I do not know how to act at a time

Comment: ok. i will try. I just can not figure out how to deysvovat in such cases, when the flow is already running and I move to another fragment.